# EJB client from interfaces

Tags: java, maven, ejb, ejb-3.0

[I read this, but cannot fix my issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685338/how-do-i-build-and-deploy-a-remote-ejb-with-maven)

I have java module where all files are java interfaces ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPWr2.png)).

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>tsm-mno-external-services</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                <clientIncludes>
                    <clientInclude>com/test/ExternalCustomerCareServicesRemote.java</clientInclude>
                </clientIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When Im run maven goal, ejb *-client.jar is not generated (In other modules with contains classed ejb *-client.jar generated without problems).

So question is next: can i generate ejb client from interfaces?

Comment: I suppose you want to have some .class in your jar, not java sources...

Comment: Compiled interfaces - stored as .class. I dont have client jar at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There as an error in my pom.xml, so *-client.jar is not generated at  package phase.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <goal>package</goal>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                <clientIncludes>
                    <clientInclude>path/**</clientInclude>
                </clientIncludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>ejb</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```